# Ubuntu 11.10: подключить интернет

Tags: сеть, ubuntu

На RoverBook-W700 установил с диска Ubuntu 11.10. Встала отлично. Ставил на голый ноут. Не подключается локальная сеть при загрузке системы. Заходил в панель управления, система сетевую карту видит.

```
Marvell Yukon 88E8038 PCI-E Fast Ethernet ControllerРазмещение: гнездо 32 MAC-адрес: 00-03-25-30-6С-44Модем-ADSL МОДЕМ ИНТЕРКРОСС ICxDSL 5633 E/UE/NE/NE-02Настроен. Его данные в Windows XP.Протокол интернета(TCP/IP)IP-адресс 192.168.1.2Маска подсети 255.255.255.0Основной шлюз 192.168.1.1Предпочитаемый DNS-сервер 217.18.130.30Альтернативный DNS-сервер 217.18.138.30
```

Windows в интернет заходит. Ubuntu 11.10 - НЕТ. Не подключается Wired. Подскажите, что и где настроить.

Answer (score 1):

В `/etc/network/interfaces` (замените на актуальные для вас значения):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 217.18.130.30
```

При условии, конечно, что сетевая определилась как `eth0`.

Посмотреть можно командой:

```
ip l
```

После внесения изменений сделать:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вручную в `/etc/network/interfaces`.